# Problems when compiling python-ast.c on win32

Tags: python, compilation

I have downloaded the [Python 2.7.1 source code](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.1/Python-2.7.1.tgz), after extraction issued this command:

```
D:\sources\Python-2.7.1>gcc -c -I.\Include -I.\PC -I.\Python .\Python\Python-ast.c
.\Python\Python-ast.c:464: error: initializer element is not constant
.\Python\Python-ast.c:464: error: (near initialization for 'AST_type.ob_type')
```

The code in question:

```
static PyTypeObject AST_type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0) //this is line 464
    "_ast.AST",
    sizeof(PyObject),
    0,
    0,                       /* tp_dealloc */
    0,                       /* tp_print */
    0,                       /* tp_getattr */
    0,                       /* tp_setattr */
    0,                       /* tp_compare */
    0,                       /* tp_repr */
    0,                       /* tp_as_number */
    0,                       /* tp_as_sequence */
    0,                       /* tp_as_mapping */
    0,                       /* tp_hash */
    0,                       /* tp_call */
    0,                       /* tp_str */
    PyObject_GenericGetAttr, /* tp_getattro */
    PyObject_GenericSetAttr, /* tp_setattro */
    0,                       /* tp_as_buffer */
    Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE, /* tp_flags */
    0,                       /* tp_doc */
    0,                       /* tp_traverse */
    0,                       /* tp_clear */
    0,                       /* tp_richcompare */
    0,                       /* tp_weaklistoffset */
    0,                       /* tp_iter */
    0,                       /* tp_iternext */
    ast_type_methods,        /* tp_methods */
    0,                       /* tp_members */
    0,                       /* tp_getset */
    0,                       /* tp_base */
    0,                       /* tp_dict */
    0,                       /* tp_descr_get */
    0,                       /* tp_descr_set */
    0,                       /* tp_dictoffset */
    (initproc)ast_type_init, /* tp_init */
    PyType_GenericAlloc,     /* tp_alloc */
    PyType_GenericNew,       /* tp_new */
    PyObject_Del,            /* tp_free */
};
```

I am using [TDM GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/):

```
gcc version 4.4.1 (TDM-1 mingw32)
```

The specified directories contain all the includes needed. Why is this happening? The code in Python-ast.c seems like standard C.

**Thanks for the help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python on Windows expects to be compiled with MSVC.  The `#define`s and the like are set up for it.  They probably look for the macro `_WIN32` or something, which is defined by MSVC and (if I remember correctly) by mingw32. Since you're compiling with mingw and not MSVC, that may be part of the problem.

I would also find out where `PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT` is defined and try to figure out what it puts on that line that can cause the error.